# How to make a DisplayAlert with Content in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to make a DisplayAlert with a togglebutton or a image in Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom `PopUp` with the needed content or use existing solutions like [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup).

With the last option, it should be easy to place a couple of buttons with a desired behaviour on a `PopUpPage`.